# Jquery countdown On Expiry

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I need some help. I am putting a jquery countdown timer on a page. the countdown I am using is http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html what I need is when one countdown expires, it will then count down to another date. So for example it will countdown to 1/08/2015. When it reaches 1/08/2015 I then want it to count down to another date. So from 1/08/2015 it will then count down to 5/08/2015. I hope that makes sense. I have successfully put the countdown itself on the page. it is just the On expiry I am having trouble with.

This is the script from the example.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var austDay = new Date();
        austDay = new Date(2015, 11 - 1, 7);
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
        $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
    });
</script>
```

It is displayed in this tag

```
<center><div id="defaultCountdown"></div></center>
```

I have made an effort towards it. This is as far as I have got but it is also as far as I can go. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();
    FirstDay = new Date(2015, 11 - 1, 7);
    SecondDay = new Date (2015, 11 - 1, 9);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: FirstDay});
});
```

**Should of mentioned that there are going to be 4 dates to countdown to in total!**

Comment: in psudo code what you need is: `if (today > FirstDay) $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: SecondDay}); else $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: FirstDay});`

Comment: $(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();
    FirstDay = new Date(2015, 7 - 1, 31, 11, 30);
    SecondDay = new Date(2015, 11 - 1, 9);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: FirstDay
    });
});

var today = new Date();
if (today > FirstDay) $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: SecondDay}); else $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: FirstDay});

Comment: I've tried including that into my code and it still does nothing when it reaches 0.

Comment: that's becasue you are only checking the date against the frist date on page load

Comment: So would i need an update function? I am not very good at Javascript. I am a bit of a newbie. I appreciate the help thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have `onExpiry` event which you can utilize and below is just a sample how you could do! Not sure if it works or not!! May be you have to trial and error.

set a global variable first to check once count has been done:

```
var count=0;

$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date(2015, 11 - 1, 7);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay,onExpiry: liftOff});
    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
});

function liftOff() { 
     if(count==0)
     {
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newDate});
        count=1;
     }
     else
        count=0;
}
```

You can find the options **[here](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#)**

---

**UPDATE**

Ok just copy and paste this below code as it is!!

**Its tested**

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/h5kmpz6e/)**

```
var count=0; //a global variable

$(function () {
    shortly = new Date(); 
    shortly.setSeconds(shortly.getSeconds() + 5.5); //for time being this will run for 5 seconds
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: shortly,onExpiry: liftOff}); 
});

function liftOff() { 
//function that gets called on expiry
   if(count==0) //check already done 2nd time, if not get in
   {
        shortly = new Date(); 
        shortly.setSeconds(shortly.getSeconds() + 5.5); //again do it for 5 secs
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('option',{until: shortly});
        //set an option here for the same counter again
        count=1; //make this 1
   }
   else
       count=0;
}
```

> The above code is present at the end of `javascript` section in the
>   above demo given

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. When the countdown reaches 0 nothing happens. Would you be able to help me make it so that when it reaches 0 it will begin another countdown to another set date. That's the bit i am struggling with.

Comment: What code shall I show you? it is the actual script I am having trouble with. The CSS is only the design. the html only displays it on the page. Its the actual script. Thank you

Comment: That's great for counting down 5 seconds haha. I cant get dates to work with it though as when I substitute the date into the script it comes up wrong. so 30 minutes when really there should only be 1 minute

Comment: @Sootay that was just a demo!! you have to change according to your needs!! See this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/h5kmpz6e/1/)**.. I have commented a date part at beginning!! These sort of solutions I cannot keep long date and wait for it  to complete, to check it its working or not!! You have to take care of this..

Comment: When i change the date and then refresh the page the counter begins from the start again. I really am at a loss here.

Comment: I'm not really following you on that sorry! I'm really lost now

Comment: for the forms I am using PHP but that is totally separate from the counter.

Comment: So what you need to do is send a value for date from server so that you can always sync the `countdown` from server on page load! there is an option called `resync` by using which you can get server values but not sure though how to use it as they have given only **`$.countdown.resync() // Re-synchronise all countdown instances with their server`** and you might need to R&D on that or if you wanna use `localStorage` then you need to modify the plugin which is very difficult though.

Comment: At the max I can show you the link which describes how to do it and here it is - > **[serverSync](http://keith-wood.name/countdownref.html#serverSync)**

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. However, I am very confident in all this and I don't know what this means. It's too complicated

Comment: It basically means that everytime you are fetching the time for `countdown` from `serverside` and even though refresh happens it will get time from serverside itself which keeps on changing and will not effect the `countdown` and since I have no knowledge on `php` I couldn't be of much help to you! Sorry for that!

Comment: I know only the front end of development! been tasked with this countdown and I'm totally lost! as I said i have got the countdown to work to one date but just cannot fathom getting it to countdown to another on expiry

Comment: do you not have anymore suggestions for me?

Comment: My suggestion is at least have the basic knowledge of `backend` and then come up with solution! otherwise its very difficult to achieve your requirement!

Comment: I do have some knowledge. Evidently not enough however.

Comment: Then you need to improve it up but as of me, as I said before I do not have little knowledge too!!

Comment: The reason i came here is for a solution

Answer (score 0):

What about comparing the date with the current date?

```
var today = new Date();
if(today<FirstDay){
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: FirstDay});
}
else if(today<=SecondDay){
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: SecondDay});
}
```

I don't want to enforce my logic here, the concept would be comparing the date with the current one. However, this approach won't work perfectly unless the client machine is set to the right time and have the same time zone, or it will have different output to each client. I prefer to do the comparison on the server side.
Edit
I changed it so that the second counter starts just after the first one

Comment: Thank you for you help, I agree with your logic. It seems like the best way but it does not work. When the countdown reaches 0 it stays at zero and does not change to the second date.

Comment: Well I was writing a concept code , use <= instead of < so that at the transition day the second counter appears

Comment: if(today<=FirstDay){
 else if(today<=SecondDay){

Tried that, still hasn't worked.

Comment: I see you only used one '=', That still doesn't work.

Comment: there would also need to be 2 more counters. so 4 altogether.

Comment: no , if(today<=FirstDay){ else if(today<=SecondDay){ is tottaly wrong 
this means that the else is inside the if that will ever throw an error ,

Comment: Please explain your problem ? is just one date working for you ?

Comment: Yes. Only the first date works. It will countdown until 0 and then just stay like that.

Comment: okay i got what's probably wrong here , to switch between the dates in this script you mush refresh the page i will make an update soon to include no need for refresh case

Comment: okay someone has a working solution before me I can't post it check Guruprasad Rao his updated one