# Quiz generator and randomization in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

Every time I add a 1 or a 2 for the correct answer it gives me something else. Can anyone help. I have also provided a Jsfiddle link that way you can see the HTML CSS and JavaScript put together. I don't know why the answers are not showing up. Or if they are they are not the correct answer.

```js
  let quiz = (function() {
    let getFinalResultsString = (score, questionsCount) => {
      //Stop timer here
      clearInterval(interval);
      score = 0;
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the `score` value to 0 in your `getFinalResultsString()` function. Remove the line `score = 0;` and it should work as expected. I've also updated your JSFiddle.

The answer for the first question is 'her' as you have set the answer index to 1; don't forget that JavaScript uses 0 based indexing.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had updated your JSFiddle, try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/m9osxran/1/).

Comment: Thank you! it worked. Also do you know how to stop the quiz as soon as the timer stops?

Comment: You seem to be doing it manually at the moment; instead you should use jquery countdown timer, which will allow you to execute code upon expiration of the timer. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31727323/4300608) SOF answer.